# Automating a request and response based app

Tags: ios, automation, regression-testing

I am trying to automate a native iOS app, which involves a customer sending a request and a sales  representative receives the request and responds.
Which tool should I use?
I want to run some UI specific test cases too.
Most automating tools don't support a request and response based app.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking is probably the most used solution for response/request (REST api) applications. It is open source, actively maintained and can be found [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Also it is pretty easy to implement and has well written [documentation](http://afnetworking.com).

Comment: Thanks Nikos but what I wanted to do is automate UI in priority, for the api I have used SoapUI and that works fine.
Just to elaborate, my project involves two different apps on different devices. From one device I send a request (like a message) and I receive it on a different device.
Is that feasible for automation?